# Changing the order of radiobuttons from radiobuttongroup

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex3

I am using RadioButtons within a radiobuttongroup. i want to change the order sequence of the radiobuttons of the group based on the end user's input.i have searched a lot, but all fell into vain.

I want to know whether it is possible to change the order of the radiobuttons?

please help me to find the solution on this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, you can change the order of objects by changing the order that they are added to their parent container (ie: change the child object's index in the parent).

You could come up w/any number of ways to do this in Flex.  If you're using Flex 4, there is a new `depth` property that orders child objects irrespective of their child index.

To get you started, you can just try using the `addChild()`, `addChildAt()`, `removeChild()`, and `removeChildAt()` methods on the parent of the radio buttons. You could consider using Flex view states for something more complex.